# Comparing Strings not Working in Java

Tags: java, string, compare

I'm  importing a string from a file and the string is "Computer_Made". If I execute this code, though, it does not print "The computer is already made!" Any ideas?

```
if (data=="Computer_Made")
    {
    computer=true;
    System.out.println("The computer is already made!");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You should use .equals for string comparison!!

```
if (data.equals("Computer_Made"))
{
computer=true;
System.out.println("The computer is already made!");
}
```

[Refer here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `String` are compared using `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` method.

Using `==` is reference equality and will rarely be the same.

Try instead:

```
if (data.equals("Computer_Made"))
```

`==` will only work in example like this:

```
String a = "Ha";
String b = a;
System.out.println("a==b :" + a==b); //prints a==b : true
```